# Project Euler 7 in C

Tags: c

I know there are many topics on this in different forums too but my problem is this:

Q 1. For Euler problem 7 (finding 10001st prime) this is my code which I thought of on my own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k=0,m=0,num;
    for(i=1;m<10001;i++)
    {
        k=0;
        for(j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j!=0)
                k++;
        }
        if(k+2==i)
        {    
            m++;
            num=i;
        }  
    }
    printf("%d %d",num,m);
}
```

This problem should display 10000th prime (m<10001) but it displays the 10001st prime, why is that?

Comment: I don't know why your program does what it does, but Project Euler is all about solving "smarter" not "harder", here are a few tips about finding primes going from simple to complex: 1)`j` only needs to test up to `j*j <= i` once you get past that point you have tested every potential divisor. 2) start `j` at 3 then increment `j` by 2, you don't need to test every even number. 3) get rid of `m`, just continue on with the next `i` when you find `i%j==0`. 4) Learn about [seives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) and use one.

Comment: Well, you could use induction. Show that it works for `m<M`, starting with `M = 1`. Then show that it works for `M → M+1`. ([Online demo of your code.](http://ideone.com/MIXEWg))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop breaks when `m` is 10001 which is reason for it printing 10001 for `m`. Since `m` starts from `0`, it prints the 10001st prime. In your code, loop runs from `0...10000` (10001 times).

Change the condition to `m<10000` i.e. loop runs from `0...9999` (10000 times) and `m` at the end of the loop will have `10000`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Euler.27s_Sieve) because it will skip checking of all the multiples of prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my optimised code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool prime(int n){ 
    if (n <= 1) 
        return false; 
    if (n <= 3) 
        return true; 
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) 
        return false; 

    for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6) 
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) 
            return false; 

    return true; 
}

int main()
{
    int arr[100000],j=0; 

    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        if(prime(i))
            arr[j++]=i;
    }
    cout << arr[99999] << endl;
}
```

I have tried to reduce the time complexity as much as possible.

Algorithm to my solution:

1) I have used the fact that every prime number is of the form 6N-1 or 6N+1, where N is the natural number.

2) To check for whether the number is prime or not it sufficient to check the factors till sqrt(number) as it will reduce the time complexity of the code.

3) I haven't used the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm as we don't the range till where we have to run the loop.