# Project 7 Euler C

Tags: c

I'm stuck at [Question 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) of Project Euler. I have this piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int contador = 0, i, n, variavel = 0;
    for (i = 0; contador == 1000; i++)
    {
        for(n = 0; n == i; n++)
        {
            if (i % n == 0)
            {
                variavel = i;
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", variavel);
}
```

It always prints 0. Why is that?

---

PS: I wrote 1000 but the answer must be the 10001st prime number.

Comment: Your for loop will never execute - see if you can work out why.

Comment: What the hell is project Euler?

Comment: This piece of code is a fantastic opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger!

Comment: I guess it's because of the n == i. But it won't only stop the second for?

Comment: Ed Heal, you should check this out. It's a website that give you math problems and you have to solve them with programming.

Comment: @BrunoFrancisco: take a closer look at the *outer* for loop.

Comment: Assuming `variavel` means "variable" and `contador` means "counter, you really should use more descriptive variable names. For variables that don't need description, try to use single letters, like `a, b, c`. The variable in the outermost for loop is also usually `x`, followed by `y` and `z`, in order.

Comment: [All possible suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739144/project-euler-7-in-c)

Comment: @Ed Heal: look at this: https://projecteuler.net/  Another great way to spend time programming and a great way to learn new tricks from other people's answers.  The most humbling site I have ever visited.

Comment: @BrunoFrancisco et al. - Not a good idea for a question to give it a title that one is expected to know. Besides I go to work to get those problems

Comment: I'll check out @Ajay link and try to figure this out.

Comment: @haneefmubarak i'm portuguese and this variables mean something to me. But i reconize that to you it doesn't mean a lot. Thanks for the information. From now on i'll try to use the letters you mentioned.

Comment: @EdHeal Thank you for the output Ed. I am still trying to figure out what is wrong with the outter loop but with no lucky so far. I'm beginning in programming right now and it's hard for me.

Comment: @BrunoFrancisco what I mean is, even in English we wouldn't use variable and counter as names. Those names don't tell us anything (what is varying? counting what?). The letters are just a convention that makes code easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for` loop consist of 3 parts

```
for( init ; cond ; step )
```

When the execution reaches the loop,

1. `init` is executed.
2. `cond` is evaluated.

   - If false, break the loop
   - If true, proceed to the next step
3. Execute the body of the loop.
4. Do `step`(in many cases, this is increment/decrement)
5. Goto step 2

So, in your code, when the execution reaches

```
for (i = 0; contador == 1000; i++)
```

`i` is set to 0. Then the condition `contador == 1000` is checked. It is false as `contador` is initialized to 0. So, the loop breaks and the execution reaches the `printf` which prints the value of `variavel` which is 0 and then

```
return 0;
```

executes. This ends the execution of your program.

Your inner `for` loop has a somewhat similar issue. If the condition of the outer `for` loop is corrected, then the inner `for` loop executes. `n` is set to zero and then, the condition `n==i` is checked. It will be true only when `i=0`,i.e, it will be true only in *the first iteration* of the outer `for` loop.

You need to correct these mistakes.

Comment: Ohhh.  I made a huge mistake. I tought that the "cond" was something to tell them when to stop. It would only stop the loop if that condition was true. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: In that case, I think you need `contador<1000` and `n!=i` as the conditions of the loops

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is always zero is that the inner loop condition is satisfied in the first iteration:

`for(n=0; n==i; n++)`

Additionally, your outer loop will never run.  It is written to say that it should *only* loop when `contador == 1000`, which can never happen as written.

Comment: Actually it never even gets to the inner loop - take a closer look at the outer loop.